# Taking data from a loop and putting it into an array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a small program that find the multiples of a number.

```
def process
    i = 1
    while i < 1000
        @value1 * i
        i + 1
    end
end
```

What I need to do is take EACH the result from the multiplication and put that into an array called `@multiple1`

Please help as this is (kind of) the first ruby program that I have written on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way to do this is the following:

```
def process
  i = 1
  @multiple1 = []
  while i < 1000
      @multiple1 << @value1 * i
      i += 1
  end
end
```

The equivalent, but more Ruby-like way looks like this:

```
@multiple1 = (1..999).map { |i| @value1 * i }
```

Comment: That should be `i += 1`

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, you're right. Blindly copied and pasted from the OP.